# No available instances to satisfy this request. App Service is attempting to increase capacity

Tags: azure

Tryin to create a App service plan in Azure but deployment is failing with the following error:

> No available instances to satisfy this request. App Service is
> attempting to increase capacity, If urgent, this can be mitigated by
> deploying this to a new resource group.

[image]

Tried in different regions but showing the above highlighted message.

Answer (score 0):

> No available instances to satisfy this request. App Service is attempting to increase capacity, If urgent, this can be mitigated by deploying this to a new resource group.

- The above error occurs when there are not enough instances available to satisfy your request.
- The region you are trying to create App service plan must have a high/enough number of plans already. So, it is not allowing you to create a new service plan.

To overcome this, you can try two ways:

1. Select a different pricing plan:

[image]

- ***You can also create in a different region.***

[image]

And the highlighted message is just a normal message saying if you are unable to find/select your Service Plan:

- When deploying your web app, select the region where your ASP is available (or)
- Deploy your app in the same region in which your ASP is created.

**Example:**
*I have selected the region `EastUS` where I have my service plan.*

[image]

Comment: I tried with Different Regions but No luck.  Actually as per client requirement , I need to select a Basic service plan where the deployment is failing. Any particular reason for not accepting the BAsic Plan ?

Comment: @vaseemakram, can you provide screenshot of the error you got when you tried with different region. Also, delete few existing plans and try again.